# Passing 2 strings through array to the where clause in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, where-clause

I want to send 2 strings through array from controller to model and get the results from db, but there is a problem I'm facing.

My controller is like:

```
$data = array();
if($query = $this->authors_model->get_authors_list(array('author_Type' => array('admin', 'author'))))
{
    $data['authors'] = $query;
}
```

My Model :

```
function get_authors_list($options = array())
{        

    if(isset($options['author_Type']))
    $this->db->where('author_Type', $options['author_Type']);

    $this->db->order_by('author_Id', 'ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get('mg_authors');

    return $query->result();
}
```

and the error I'm getting:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php
>
> Line Number: 427

---

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT * FROM (`mg_authors`) WHERE `author_Type` = Array ORDER BY
>   `author_Id` ASC LIMIT 15
>
> Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\sport\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

Comment: You are passing `$options['author_Type']` array to `AR::where()` method, which generates `author_Type = Array`. that's an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use WHERE IN when you put array. In CodeIgniter, it need to do like this:

```
$this->db->where_in('author_Type', $options['author_Type']);
```